# SPA authorization with react router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Follow up of this question: [React Router Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898264/react-router-authorization)

I understand the example provided here

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js

But I think this only answers the question of authentication and not authorization. Wheter the user is authenticated or not only depends on the presence of a value at the location there should be a jwt token in local storage.

```
 loggedIn() {
   return !!localStorage.token
 }
```

I know it will be impossible to do any server communication but what I'm after is completely hide my application behind a login. I don't see how I can achieve this in a SPA, should I split up my authentication and the rest of my application as 2 pages? What if I bring in roles?

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the user role in to the component through props and perform a simple check to see if the user should be allowed to access this page. Redirect(possibly to a 404 page) otherwise.

```
const UserPage = ({userType}) => {    
    if(userType.role == 'user' || userType.role == 'admin') {
        return (
            <div>Basic Page Accessed</div>
        )
    } else {
        // Redirect
    }
}

const AdminPage = ({userType}) => {    
    if(userType.role == 'admin') {
        return (
            <div>Page Accessed</div>
        )
    } else {
        // Redirect
    }
}
```

Of course this isn't at all secure because everything occurs in the client side and there's nothing stopping a malicious/savvy user from firing off actions that they're not supposed to. That's why you also need to use authentication/authorisation on your backend too. So you can think of my example as more of a nice UI feature rather than an actual security feature. You could also use [this](http://github.stfi.re/burczu/react-router-role-authorization?sf=xzpowgr#aa) library for front end authorisation but it seems like a bit much to me. The simple solution should do the trick.

The question then becomes one of authorisation/authentication of an API which is well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication).

Of course this approach really only secures your *data* and not your actual *application* but I guess that's sufficient for most apps. If you really needs to block access to different pages completely then I guess React or some other SPA framework may not be the best for the project.